# Empty lines were added to PHP and CSS code files between each line

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, administrator

When I install the module from Joomla administrator end, I found that many empty lines were added to PHP and CSS code files between each line.

For example:

Original:

---

Line1
Line2
Line3

---

After uploading to joomla,

Line1

Line2

Line3

Comment: Hi zhang, thank you for transferring your question here from Stack Overflow.  Now we need to improve the quality of your question and make it complete.  Please offer more specifics as to what module you are loading.  While files exactly were corrupted in this fashion?  I looks like your text went from having no newlines to having double newlines.  What operating system / environment is your Joomla installation running on?  Please take out [tour].  Please edit your question to provide as many relevant details as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Zhang,

Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange!

It's as simple as \r\n vs \n - text files deal with differently encoded line breaks depending on where you view them. The reverse can happen when you download a file and open it in various programs, and you'll find what was closed up online is double spaced in the editor.

Because each OS have different ASCII chars for linebreak, the combinations give different results when viewed on other platforms:
windows = \r\n
unix = \n
mac = \r

It comes down to which editor the creator of the module used to create their files.

It doesn't cause any harm aside from readability.